# Automapper WebApi middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, automapper

I have a lot of controller methods and most of them have the same duplicating code

```
[Route("test"), HttpPost]
public ResponceViewModel Test(RequestViewModel model)
{
  Model data = model.MapTo<Model>();

  ResponceModel responce = service.DoWork(data);

  return responce.MapTo<ResponceViewModel>();
}
```

Is it feasible to create WebApi middleware that does mapping by default. What I mean is that it checks if there is mapping between ResponceViewModel and ResponceModel and if such exists executes it. This way i will not need to write this code in every method? I will probably create some attribute to have control to stop this functionality on certain endpoints if needed. Is this good approach, if not why?

Comment: You tagged this as both ASP.NET Web API 2, and ASP.NET Core Web API. The two are mutually exclusive. Which are you using?

Comment: I am currently using ASP.NET Web API 2, but there are plans for migration to ASP.NET Core. For what i have seen till now everything supported by old WebApi is supported by WebApi Core. but by different form.(At least what i am using)

Comment: I have removed the extra tag then. Your question should be specific to the framework you're actually trying to get a solution for.